# Ansible: Inline data for file-update

Tags: ansible

I need to update some files via Ansible playbook.

Normally my playbook would connect to the site where the new files are stored and transfers them.

The question is if there is a way to have the content of the new files integrated inside the playbook to have it bundled together without needing to have a download site.

I think of HTML and images. You can reference to another file or also can have it inlined Base64 encoded.

**EDIT**

Just found module copy supports inline data.

```
- name: Creating a file with content
    copy:
      dest: "x.x"
      content: |
        line1abc  xyz
        yxz000  123
        blabla *** ...
```

Thats a possible way for me. Maybe there is some better - let me know please.

Comment: by default the `ansible.builtin.copy` module looks for files in the `files/` subdir of the current directory (or relative to the role's root if in a role). Can't you just put the file there? It'll have the same result as inlining it and will look much less cluttered.

Answer (score -1):

While your approach with `ansible.builtin.copy` and `content` works, it will not scale for large numbers of files.

I would suggest you take a look at the docs for [`ansible.posix.synchronize`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) and [`ansible.builtin.git`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/git_module.html)

The synchronize-module is basically a wrapper around rsync.

For html-files or any other code, you should use git anyway, so you can leverage it for the file-transfer.  The `depth`-attribute of the `git`-module is of interest here: you probably want a shallow clone with a depth of 1 on your webserver, not a full clone of your local repo.